# Is there a metaphor to say "it's named this way for a reason"

Tags: phrase-requests, metaphors

I was wondering is there an English or American metaphor or phrase to say it has been called this way for a reason? Suppose I want to say this

> The private key is called private for a reason!

Is there an expression that sounds more like a native!

Comment: '... for a reason' is very natural/idiomatic in English.

Answer (score 3):

**The clue is in the name.**

A fixed expression (too transparent to be an idiom), with over 8.5 million hits on Google.

Some examples:

- *The Clue is in the Name. Was ever a whisky better named than Rosebank? It has always been considered a fragrant single malt ....*  [[Rosebank Distillery](https://www.rosebank.com/our-journal/the-clue-is-in-the-name)]
- *John West No Drain Tuna: The clue is in the name* [[John West](https://adsofbrands.net/en/ads/john-west-no-drain-tuna-the-clue-is-in-the-name/5135)]
- *'Private member club'. The clue is in the name. Private clubs, and hence club dining outlets, are not open to the public.  Privacy – perhaps better expressed as exclusivity – is one of the primary reasons members join in the first place ....* [[T Tassitano; RSM](https://rsmus.com/what-we-do/industries/private-clubs/the-circle-of-truth-a-club-is-not-a-restaurant.html)] [tweaked]

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **self-explanarory** comes to mind.

"private key" is a self-explanatory term.

> - "easy to understand without explanation" [**1**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/self-explanatory)
> - "understandable without explanation; self-evident" [**2**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-explanatory)